# Router and access point: Why are IP devices not visible between the two?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point, camera

My network has a TP-Link Archer C7 as a router connected to the ISP and a TP-Link Archer A7 configured as an access point connected by cable to the router.  Both support 2.4/5GHz with main and guest SIDs for each band, and both have been configured with the same SIDs to support convenient roaming between.

My desktop is cabled to the access point.  I have an IP camera connected via WiFi to the router.  What would explain why my desktop cannot ping the camera on the router?  If I WiFi connect that camera (or any other camera) to the access point, my desktop can ping it fine.  My phone has an app that can connect to these cameras and it can connect to all four cameras regardless of whether they are connected to the router or the access point.

When I use the Tether app (provided by TP-Link), all of the devices connected to the access point (whether cabled or WiFi) appear as cabled devices under the router.  I admit that, while I have general networking experience, I am new to access points so maybe there is some configuration I need to adjust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have the wireless router on a different subnet from the main network. Set it up as follows:

1. Hook up a LAN port on the wireless router to a LAN port on the main network.
2. Log into the wireless router and give it a Static IP address on the main network (so it does not get lost when you reset the network).
3. Turn DHCP OFF on the wireless router.

Now everything is on one subnet, everything gets an IP Address from the main network, and everything should be able see both routers.

Comment: I already had them connected LAN port/port and had a static address. But I hadn't disabled DHCP on the access point.  That was apparently the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the update and I was happy to help