# How to use a raspberry pi as an access point to eduroam?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi

How can I connect to eduroam via a raspberry pi?

Can the raspberry pi communicate over wi-fi with another eduroam access point and re-broadcast that connection either over wifi or ethernet?

I've found articles about how to connect a pi to eduroam itself, but not about how to make a pi an access point for eduroam. Seems more complicated than making it an access point for a "standard" network, because every user on eduroam needs to supply their own personal credentials and the pi should just be a gateway for users to do that.

Answer (score 3):

> How to use a raspberry pi as an access point to eduroam?

It's very similar to making it a "normal" access point, except you have to additionally enable WPA-EAP and 802.1X in the `hostapd` service configuration.

```
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
ieee8021x=1
auth_server_addr=<IPADDRESS>
auth_server_port=1812
auth_server_shared_secret=<PASSWORD>
```

For this to work, you **must have access** to a member institution's RADIUS server (preferably, of course, one that belongs to the institution that you're physically at...) – if you were working for the institution, your network team would tell you the RADIUS server's address and a 'shared secret' for securing communications between the server and the access point.

If you're not actually working for the institution – do not try to set up an eduroam access point, and **do not** use the "eduroam" SSID or they'll be very annoyed.

> Can the raspberry pi communicate over wi-fi with another eduroam access point and re-broadcast that connection either over wifi or ethernet?

Now that's a completely different question from the title... and it's actually 3 separate questions:

1. "Can a raspberry pi connect to another eduroam access point?"

   Sure, just tell wpa_supplicant (or iwd) to use WPA-EAP and provide your account information. Many institutions already provide eduroam setup instructions for Linux users.
2. "Can a raspberry pi re-broadcast that connection over ethernet?"

   Yes, like with any other network connection.
3. "Can a raspberry pi re-broadcast that connection over wifi?"

   Yes, like with any other network connection – but you will have to use a *different SSID,* and it will need to be a simple "passphrase-protected" SSID using WPA-PSK (because you don't have the necessary access to set up WPA-EAP).

Comment: Why does it need some kind of shared secret to be an access point? Can't it just pass all information from devices connected to itself to the other access point, and then back the other way, to be some invisible access point?

Comment: Why isn't something similar to this possible: https://superuser.com/a/1554778/325613